# System.NoAccessException: Script-thrown exception while trying to access record type in managed package

Tags: managed-package, record-type, production

We are encountering a problem in our production environment when trying to run the following line of code in developer console to retrieve the record type. The app is a managed package but we are trying to extend it to add extra functionality. This line is supposed to resolve an error for a test that is failing in production. Anyone with ideas why the following error is being thrown?

System.NoAccessException: Script-thrown exception

```
invRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.AVAB__SO_Document__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
      .get('Invoice')
      .getRecordTypeId();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the package a Site License or User based license? If the latter, I would check the running user has a license for the package.

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC. turns out the running user hadn't been assigned the license.